# Angularjs d3 custom directive with filter on data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm new to AngularJS and D3.js. I would like to build a bar column graph with some data. I am following the [Cloudspace](http://cloudspace.com/blog/2014/03/25/creating-d3.js-charts-using-angularjs-directives/#.VMCgxmPaD6E) tutorial and was able to build the graph successfully.

Now I wanted to try one step ahead. My data is as follows in my controller:

```js
$scope.myData = [
    {'name': 'AngularJS', '#count': '300'},
    {'name': 'D3.JS', '#count': '150'},
    {'name': 'jQuery', '#count': '400'},
    {'name': 'Backbone.js', '#count': '300'},
    {'name': 'Ember.js', '#count': '100'}
];
```

and also I written my own custom filter:

```js
App.filter('filterMyData', function() {
    return function(data, filterFor) {
        var property = Object.keys(filterFor)[0];
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i][property].indexOf(filterFor[property]) > -1) {
                result.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

Now how can I build the graph with the filtered data in run time? I don't want to hard-code my filter value in directive code. In my html it should be either:

```
<my-bar data="myData | filterMyData:{'#count': '300'}"></my-bar>
```

or

```
<my-bar data="myData" filter="{'#count': '300'}"></my-bar>
```

I googled a lot and couldn't find any proper solution. I may be doing wrong, hence correct me or suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

It's more a suggestion than a solution, but I think you should look at https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives if you only want to draw bar chart. It simplifies a lot the D3.js settings.

Using it, you can filter your model before using it into the directive.
For your filtering issue, there is several solutions, e.g.:

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    return $filter('filterMyData')($scope.myData, '300');
};
```

And on your directive

```
<my-bar data="getData()"></my-bar>
```

Comment: "Using it, you can filter your model before using it into the directive." - Could you please give me some examples or show me the direction for this?